# git_bash code command not working in VS-code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

hello everyone i just installed VS-Code and Git-Bash on windows 10 but when i type code hello.py on terminal it gives me the error "bash: code: command not found"
is there any solution for that

Thank You

Comment: What do you think "code" does? I've never heard this command, if you just want to run your hello.py then type python hello.py

Comment: Dear @zack6849 it will open hello.py file on my VS-Code

Comment: If code is supposed to open vscode, try rebooting your computer, it sounds like git bash can't find code.exe in your PATH variable.

Comment: ok Thanks i will

Comment: Dear @zack6849 Thank you for your comment and it works.